# How to reduce size of footnote in kableExtra (LaTeX)

Tags: r, latex, kableextra

I have the following table created in Rmarkdown using the `kableExtra` package. I'm looking for a way to reduce the size of my footnote. Adding `size = 1` as an argument in the `footnote` argument appears to not work. Any ideas?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

data <- structure(list(Category = c("Internally Managed", "Externally Managed", 
"Asset Swaps", "Total"), Percent = c("44.1%", "32.5%", "23.4%", 
"100%")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

data %>%
 kable(format='latex',booktabs=TRUE, align = 'lr',
        caption="Breakdown \\label{Table3}") %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position", full_width = T), font_size = 9) %>% 
  row_spec(0,bold=T,color = 'white', background = '#7c3042') %>% 
  row_spec(1:4, hline_after = T) %>% 
  row_spec(4, bold = T) %>% 
  column_spec(1:2, width = '5cm') %>% 
  footnote(general = "*This is what I want my footnote to be", threeparttable = TRUE, size = 7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some LaTeX code and escape (`escape = F`) them to achieve a smaller font size on your footnote.

One reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Footnote"
author: "bttomio"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```

```{r evensmallerfootnote}
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

data <- structure(list(Category = c("Internally Managed", "Externally Managed", 
"Asset Swaps", "Total"), Percent = c("44.1%", "32.5%", "23.4%", 
"100%")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

data %>%
 kable(format='latex',booktabs=TRUE, align = 'lr',
        caption="Breakdown \\label{Table3}") %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position", full_width = T), font_size = 9) %>% 
  row_spec(0,bold=T,color = 'white', background = '#7c3042') %>% 
  row_spec(1:4, hline_after = T) %>% 
  row_spec(4, bold = T) %>% 
  column_spec(1:2, width = '5cm') %>% 
  footnote(general = "\\\\tiny{*This is what I want my footnote to be}", threeparttable = TRUE, escape = F)
```


```{r smallerfootnote}
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

data <- structure(list(Category = c("Internally Managed", "Externally Managed", 
"Asset Swaps", "Total"), Percent = c("44.1%", "32.5%", "23.4%", 
"100%")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

data %>%
 kable(format='latex',booktabs=TRUE, align = 'lr',
        caption="Breakdown \\label{Table3}") %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position", full_width = T), font_size = 9) %>% 
  row_spec(0,bold=T,color = 'white', background = '#7c3042') %>% 
  row_spec(1:4, hline_after = T) %>% 
  row_spec(4, bold = T) %>% 
  column_spec(1:2, width = '5cm') %>% 
  footnote(general = "\\\\footnotesize{*This is what I want my footnote to be}", threeparttable = TRUE, escape = F)
```

```{r footnote}
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

data <- structure(list(Category = c("Internally Managed", "Externally Managed", 
"Asset Swaps", "Total"), Percent = c("44.1%", "32.5%", "23.4%", 
"100%")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

data %>%
 kable(format='latex',booktabs=TRUE, align = 'lr',
        caption="Breakdown \\label{Table3}") %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position", full_width = T), font_size = 9) %>% 
  row_spec(0,bold=T,color = 'white', background = '#7c3042') %>% 
  row_spec(1:4, hline_after = T) %>% 
  row_spec(4, bold = T) %>% 
  column_spec(1:2, width = '5cm') %>% 
  footnote(general = "*This is what I want my footnote to be", threeparttable = TRUE, escape = F)
```
````

-output

[image]

You can follow [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249415/235920):

[image]